# Coulomb's static friction in multidimensional case - decide which mass begins to move

Tags: friction, oscillators, coupled-oscillators

Consider a system of N coupled oscillators, under the effect of elastic forces, damping, dynamic and static friction and an external force; for simplicity, let's suppose $N=3$. The friction model is Coulomb-Morin's friction:

$F =\cases{
-F_d \cdot sign(v)   & with $v \neq 0$ and $F_d$ known real constant\\
F_s                 & with $v = 0$ and $F_s \in \mathbb{R} \; \big\vert \; -F_{s,max} \leq F_s \leq F_{s,max}$ 
}$

The problem is how to determine the value of $F_s$. In the simple unidimensional case, the reasoning is: if exists a force, with satisfies $-F_{s,max} \leq F_s \leq F_{s,max}$ and is able to keep the mass at $v=0$, then that is the value of $F_s$. In the multidimensional case, I have this situation:
at instant time $t=t_0$, we have $v_1(t_0) = v_2(t_0) = 0$. In order to keep the zero velocity, the requested forces are $F_1$ and $F_2$, with $F_1 > F_{s,max}$ and $F_2 > F_{s,max}$. Since these forces exceed the limit of static friction, at least one mass must change its velocity to a nonzero value.

Since the "growth time" of the friction force is zero (due to its discontinuity at $v=0$), none of the forces $F_i$ reaches the limit $F_{s,max}$ before the other; at time $t = t_0 - dt$ we have $F_1 < F_{s,max}$ and $F_2 < F_{s,max}$, while at $t = t_0$ we have $F_1 > F_{s,max}$ and $F_2 > F_{s,max}$.

My question is: which mass begins to move? (only mass 1, only mass 2 or both?) The problem is that there isn't a mass which reaches the "limit value" $F_{s,max}$ before the other, since the two forces change value immediately (discontinuous function). Without a finite growth time of the function, I have no idea how to "decide" which static friction ($F_1$ or $F_2$ "breaks" first. Should I consider a finite growth time for static friction?

I have already written the motion equations, in order to calculate the static friction forces required to keep the zero velocity at $t=t_0$.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange Physics! Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See our [meta site](//meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5958) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Comment: this is not a homework; I have tried to solve the problem for days with several approaches; for example, I used a smooth approximation of Coulomb friction and solved the system of motion equations with a numerical algorithm. Now, I am trying to face the problem using a discontinuous model of friction; from my point of view, this is not a trivial homework-like question and the problem seems quite specific: how to determine the value of static friction in multidimensional case, considering a discontinuous friction model?

Comment: In my opinion, this question is asking about the problem of deciding which mass begins to move, and how one would go about deciding that. That falls under the "asking about a principle" rubric and makes this on topic.